# Установка свойства “checked” в флаговой кнопке с помощью jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Я бы хотел сделать что-то подобное, чтобы отметить флаговую кнопку, используя **jQuery**:

```
$(".myCheckBox").checked(true);
```

или

```
$(".myCheckBox").selected(true);
```

Это возможно?

<sub>Перевод вопроса «[Setting “checked” for a checkbox with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/)» [@tpower](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18107/).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### jQuery 1.6+

Используйте новую функцию [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop):

```
$('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', true);
$('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', false);
```

### jQuery 1.5.x и ниже

Функция `.prop()` недоступна, поэтому воспользуйтесь [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr).

```
$('.myCheckbox').attr('checked', true);
$('.myCheckbox').attr('checked', false);
```

Учтите, что это подход, [используемый при модульном тестировании jQuery до версии 1.6](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.5.2/test/unit/attributes.js#L157), более предпочтительный, чем

```
$('.myCheckbox').removeAttr('checked');
```

Поскольку последний, при изначально отмеченной флаговой кнопке, меняет поведение вызова на [`.reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.reset) на любую содержащую его форму – изменение хоть и не такое заметное, но нежелательное.

Вникнуть в контекст вы можете, ознакомившись с незавершённой дискуссией об изменениях в обработке атрибута/свойства `checked` при переходе от версий 1.5.x к 1.6, которая находится в [информации к версии 1.6](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/03/jquery-16-released/) и в разделе **Attributes vs. Properties** [`.prop()`-документации](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

### Любая версия jQuery

Если вы работаете всего лишь с одним элементом,вы всегда можете просто поменять свойство [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)'а `.checked`:

```
$('.myCheckbox')[0].checked = true;
$('.myCheckbox')[0].checked = false;
```

Преимущество использования вместо этого функций `.prop()` и `.attr()` состоит в том, что они будут работать со всеми элементами, соответствующими заданным условиям.

<sub>Перевод ответа «[Setting “checked” for a checkbox with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/426276/564240)» [@Xian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4642/).</sub>