# не работает checked в JS

Tags: javascript

Есть форма, в которой меняются пола в зависимости от положения радиопереключателя.
Но при обновлении страницы, радиопереключатель стоит в нужном положении, а форма не показывается.
затем, когда переключатель меняюш, все работает как нужно.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".js-tilda-rule").change(function() {
    
        if ($('#pay1').attr("checked")) {
          $('#button1').show();
        } else {
          $('#button1').fadeOut(0);
        }
 if ($('#pay2').attr("checked")) {
      $('#button2').show();
    } else {
      $('#button2').fadeOut(0);
    }
      });
    });
```

и сам HTML

```
<label class="radio__control t-text t-text_xs">
            <input type="radio" name="paymant" id="pay1" value="При получении на почте" checked="checked" class="radio js-tilda-rule">
            <div class="radio__indicator"></div>При получении на почте</label>
<label class="radio__control t-text t-text_xs">
            <input type="radio" name="paymant" id="pay2" value="Хочу оплатить на карту (экономия 40 грн)" class="radio js-tilda-rule"><div class="radio__indicator"></div>Хочу оплатить на карту (экономия 40 грн)</label> 

<button class="button" id="button1" style="display: none;">Оформить заказ1</button>
  <button class="button" id="button2" style="display: none;">Оформить заказ2</button></form>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Установка свойства “checked” в флаговой кнопке с помощью jQuery](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/517241/%d0%a3%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-checked-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-tilda-rule").change(function() {
    ...
  }).change();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const onChange = () => {
  if ($('#pay1').prop("checked")) {
    $('#button1').show();
    $('#button2').hide();
  } else {
    $('#button2').show();
    $('#button1').hide();
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".radio").change(onChange);
  
  onChange();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="radio__control t-text t-text_xs">
            <input type="radio" name="paymant" id="pay1" value="При получении на почте" checked class="radio js-tilda-rule">
            <div class="radio__indicator"></div>
            При получении на почте
  </label>
<label class="radio__control t-text t-text_xs">
            <input type="radio" name="paymant" id="pay2" value="Хочу оплатить на карту (экономия 40 грн)" class="radio js-tilda-rule"><div class="radio__indicator"></div>Хочу оплатить на карту (экономия 40 грн)</label>

<button class="button" id="button1" style="display: none;">Оформить заказ1</button>
<button class="button" id="button2" style="display: none;">Оформить заказ2</button></form>
```